# Replacement for Java 11 method String.isBlank() in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-11

I have a project developed in Java 11 and have to adapt in another, but using Java 8.

Some part of this Java 11 project uses the `String` method `isBlank()`, that is not recognized in Java 8. What is the best approach to adapt this method in Java 8 project?

Comment: Rewrite it yourself.

Comment: Replace it with `s.matches("\\p{IsWhite_Space}*")`.

Comment: You can very well write your own implementation if you care to look into the implementation. The post linked suggests *Before Java 11* implementation as well.

Comment: or `s.chars().allMatch(Character::isWhitespace)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Best approach would be to use Apache Commons [`StringUtils.isBlank(String)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isBlank-java.lang.CharSequence-)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

1. uses a commonly used library
2. proven
3. uses centralized code
4. is very similar to the source that has to be converted
5. Not falling for 'Not invented here' syndrome